# I've downloaded Ubuntu and it won't open as the file is damaged

Tags: downloads

I downloaded Ubuntu, but it says the file is damaged and it won't open. Since I've contributed nearly $30 dollars I don't want to pay twice. Please how do I download it again ?

Comment: You paid for ubuntu?

Comment: @FranciscoV. you can donate.

Comment: You don't open the downloaded file, you burn it to either a DVD or a flash drive. Use Imgburn for burning a DVD and [Rufus](rufus.akeo.ie) for making a flash drive. Ubuntu is a separate OS. It doesn't just install a program.

Comment: And Ubuntu is free. That contribution is optional and can be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Just download it again without paying anything...
Go at the [end of the page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.04.3&architecture=amd64) and click on "[Not now, take me to the download ›](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you/?version=14.04.3&architecture=amd64)"

You might also consider downloading via the official torrents, since there you have already an integrated integrity check.

Comment: The official torrent , what is it ? I thought those were alternative torrents ? I used the regular download. I'll try the torrents. Thanks.

Comment: The torrents listed [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) at the end of the page are alternative download methods, as official as the download from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pay to download Ubuntu. If you chose to make a donation when going through the download page, that's great. But you don't need to do so to download Ubuntu. You can click *Not now, take me to the download >* on the donation page, to skip the donation, and go to the download.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought maybe it was obligatory to donate before downloading.  Thanks ! I've already donated once, so my conscience is O.K. I believe in contributing always to anything that I use. Thanks again.